# Forbidden Multiline string: for the template

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

I am new to tslint and typescript.
I am trying to fix this error. Forbidden Multiline string:

Can you tell me how to fix it.
I did some research but not able to find solutions.
It's pointing to this line

```
template: `<div id="sportsData"></div>`
```

providing code below.
I even looked at this link and tried but not able to proceed

https://github.com/Microsoft/tslint-microsoft-contrib

**Forbidden Multiline string:**

```or-tag-here
@Component({
  selector: "sports",
  template: `<div id="sportsData"></div>`
})
```

Comment: Can you add the exact and full error message to your question? Where are you getting it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this character: `
I have heard this called both a **backtick** and **backquote**.
ES6+ uses it for [Template Strings](https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/#template-strings).

I am not exactly sure why, but the **no-multiline-string** TSLint rule forbids that backtick used in this way.
You will also see the same error if you try to use it in the Component Styles.

To fix the error just replace your code with this:

```
template: '<div id="sportsData"></div>'
```

If you are set on using it this way, you can always turn oof the rule by adding the following to your tslint.json:

```
"no-multiline-string": true,
```